# Is there any way to add the custom field in the Signin page in azure b2c?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Is there any way to add the custom field in the Signin page in azure b2c also with the forget password and signup links**.**

Comment: Can we know what is your scenario of adding custom fields in signin page

Comment: Are you using user flow or a custom policy?

Comment: custom policy @Carl Zhao

Comment: I want to add country code in login page also that page should show link for signup page @Raghavendra

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use an orchestration step with `Type=CombinedSignInAndSignUp` and also modify the Sign In page elements. This step type will always default to username/password regardless of adding output claims to the selfAsserted technical profile that controls the Sign In function.

The only option is to use a normal ClaimsExchange step type, which will render a generic Self Asserted page. This will not include the built in Sign Up/Password reset links. And therefore you will have to create a separate journey for Sign Up, and embed your own link to the Applications Sign Up endpoint (which sends you to the AAD B2C sign up policy).

Comment: thanks for your answer. As it looks weird that azure b2c custom policy does not provide this simple use case at ease. Is this feature is likely to be in a future release?

Comment: We are considering changing the "propriety" combinedSignInAndSignUp type claimsExchange to a generic SelfAssserted type page, but there is no ETA for it since its already possible to do based on my answer.

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT hello, I tried your answer to use ```Type=ClaimsExchange``` instead of ```Type=CombinedSignInAndSignUp``` then I added my ```InputClaim``` and ```OutputClaim```  for my custom claim in my Self-Asserted technical profile for sign-in also in ```login-NonInteractive``` but  the claim is still not displayed in the page. Besides those must there be other elements to update?

Comment: If you add it in the validation technical profile AND the self asserted technical profile, it won’t appear. ONLY add it to the self asserted technical profile.